# During a search, how can I get Excel to highlight the matches within a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, highlighting

In Excel 2016, I have some cells which contain a lot of text. When I try to search for a word in the sheet, instead of highlighting the matches within the cell, it only selects the whole found cell.

I came across a pseudo-solution with the [top answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1130500/112234), but unfortunately, it permanently changes the text's colour. I just want it to temporarily change colour whilst that match is currently active during the search.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by *whilst that match is currently active during the search*?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Works with a single match, but say you have ten matches, and you click "find next", well the next one would be highlighted (and thus 'active').

Comment: **Top answer here**, is VB codes and it's effect is always permanent and can't be Undo. One alternative method is conditional format the range to match with cell value.

Comment: You can modify the code (or write your own) to just find one at a time.  And, in the code execution, clear the formatting on all the cells before going on to the next.